# I have a Nikon D5100. What lenses would be good for landscape and night photography?

Tags: lens, landscape, nikon-d5100

I am fairly new to photography.  My family and I will be going on a trip around Australia in July and I wanted some advice on what lenses to use for landscape photography and night photography. My camera is a Nikon D5100.

Comment: What sort of night photography?

Answer (score 2):

Without more information specifically about how you envision "landscape" or "night" photography, no one can really give you a specific recommendation without relying on assumptions or their own personal preferences in these matters.

For landscape, it really depends on what/how you plan to shoot. Some folks use telephotos, others use ultrawides, others do just find with middling widish-to-normal 35e and 50e lenses. Landscape may not be about the lens as much as about what's in front of the lens. :)

With night photography, you probably want a fast lens which opens up to a wider aperture, but again, it depends on what type of night photography you plan to do. Northern lights vs. light trails from car headlights have very different requirements. Milky way vs. night-time street shooting similarly have very different requirements.

I will say, however, that the one thing you could buy that would benefit both of those types of photography, possibly more than a lens, would be **a tripod** to support your camera.  Tripods allow you to use very slow shutter speeds without introducing blur from camera shake into the image. With landscape this means you can use a low iso and stop the lens down for depth of field, and not have to worry about handholding the camera steady.  For night-time photography, it can open up entire new areas of long-exposure photography you can't possibly accomplish with handholding.

Answer (score 1):

For night (or in general low-light) photography you want a lens with the widest aperture (lowest f-number) you can afford, as this will allow you to capture more light and reduce the need for longer exposure (which causes motion blur) and/or higher ISO (which causes noise).

Comment: Thankyou for that.  Would a 50mm 1.8D be suitable?

Comment: Yes, f/1.8 is about as wide as you can get without going into "pro"-oriented equipment with prices to match. Of course, whether 50mm is suitable to you is another matter, but that is out of the scope of this answer (which is is only about things specific to low-light situations).

Comment: No, Christina! This is SUPER important. The 50mm 1.8D will not autofocus with the D5100. If you want autofocus, you need to get the 50mm 1.8G.

Comment: With a crop body camera like the D5100 you should probably also consider the very affordable Nikon AF-S DX NIKKOR 35mm f/1.8G. A 50mm lens might be a little too narrow on the APS-C camera.

Comment: For landscape photography, most of your shots will probably be taken with a focal length smaller than 30 mm (I'm almost always using the 18mm on my 18-105mm when it comes to landscape), so even the 35mm may be a bit long.

Answer (score 1):

There are really two questions in one: landscape, and night photography.

For landscape, you probably want a wide angle, and most likely a zoom (as opposed to fixed focal length, aka prime lens) because you don't always have the option of getting closer or further to change your composition. Unless you have very specific needs, any wide angle zoom will do. You don't care about aperture, and image quality will always be good enough unless you're planning very, very large printouts. I personally use either a 18-105mm or a 10-24mm for landscape. I like my 10-24mm ultra-wide very much for that.

For night photography, assuming you mean hand-held pictures, there are two important factors:

- lens stabilization,
- aperture.

Unfortunately, one usually can't get both in the Nikon world: the lens with widest apertures are usually prime lens and most prime lens do not have image stabilization. So, using a prime lens does not necessarily give you better low-light capabilities. OTOH, prime lens with a very wide aperture give you a very shallow depth of field at their widest aperture. This is good for artistic effect (nice bokeh, ...), but it also makes it easy to miss a shot (get the focus wrong by 10 centimeters in a portrait with your prime lens wide open and you can throw you picture away). If you're fairly new to photograph, a zoom with image stabilization will be much more forgiving (actually, one reason to use a prime lens is that they are not so forgiving, so they force the photograph to get better which is good in the long run).